# How can I statically link with glibc

Tags: c, linux, gcc

As I need to run my compiled program on another distro, and without static linking it just gives me the error that the version of `glibc` is not found on that computer.

Comment: Why'd you tagged it gcc then ?

Comment: @Eregrith Maybe because he wanted to know a solution for the GCC linker? Just a guess.

Comment: @junix OP edited his post, he first stated that he uses clang and not gcc so I guess: no, maybe he didn't.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [link options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) of the GCC linker. Especially the options `-static` respectively `-static-libgcc` and please read also the comments to these options, as there are sometimes reasons to not bind statically and rather deploy the shared library with the program.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the [-static](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#index-static-1040) option to `gcc`

But I believe that statically linking the Glibc is a bad idea.

<sup>(you could distribute your program in source form with a free software license; then you could package it for several distributions)</sup>

Comment: I'm afraid you put the wrong link in your posting as it points to `-fopenmp` of the compiler instead of `-static` of the linker. ;-) (edit: corrected a typo "long" instead of "wrong")